# Amazon Alexa Smart Home : Unable to discover device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am having an issue in Discovery.

when I discover devices, it does not appear to be calling the Lambda function that I have defined. The Lambda function is configured on the Skill and the event source is configured on the Lambda function.

I have check from monitoring logs that lambda function is not getting called when I try to discover devices from Alexa interface.

If I try to test same using lambda test interface it gives me the response.

Sample request being made from lambda test interface

```
{
    "header": {
        "messageId": "6d6d6e14-8aee-473e-8c24-0d31ff9c17a2",
        "name": "DiscoverAppliancesRequest",
        "namespace": "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discovery",
        "payloadVersion": "2"
    },
    "payload": {
        "accessToken": "some string"
    }
}
```

Response I got from my API endpoint is as below

```
 {
  "header": {
    "messageId": "6d6d6e14-8aee-473e-8c24-0d31ff9c17a2",
    "name": "DiscoverAppliancesResponse",
    "namespace": "Alexa.ConnectedHome.Discovery",
    "payloadVersion": "2"
  },
  "payload": {
    "discoveredAppliances": [
      {
        "actions": [
          "incrementPercentage",
          "decrementPercentage",
          "setPercentage",
          "turnOn",
          "turnOff"
        ],
        "additionalApplianceDetails": {
          "serialNumber": "CRED DEVICE 1456842949167",
          "firmwareVersion": "0.7.1.1"
        },
        "applianceId": "d4cab60d-b2e5-4d0f-ae50-c566e0de26ce",
        "friendlyDescription": "Den",
        "friendlyName": "Den",
        "isReachable": true,
        "manufacturerName": "CredSmartLabs",
        "modelName": "H+1140-87-",
        "version": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If the Lambda function itself is never being called, there is a problem with your configuration. Ensure everything is setup correctly, perhaps start over and follow the set up step by step making sure everything is right. Is your lambda event handler set up right? Does your Handler match up with your exports.handler function  in the Lambda config?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same same issue. No discover requests were sent to my lambda function. The error was that I've entered an invalid application id for the Trigger > Smart Home Trigger.

This needs to be the same value as your skill application id.

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical problem: Alexa was not able to discover my device. But unlike @RenRen, I did not use any Alexa simulator. Mine was a proper Amazon Echo device.

So I confirm that all Alexa devices will face the same issue, if there is a region mismatch.

Problem: I followed the tutorial
https://github.com/alexa-samples/skill-sample-python-smarthome-switch/blob/master/instructions/README.md
*verbatim*.

That tutorial *assumed* that I stay in North America, but never made this assumption explicit.
Since I live in India, I must have created my Lambda in the EU-West-1 region (Ireland) ! This was not at all obvious, and the tutorial never mentioned this anywhere. I fail to understand Amazon's logic behind tying up a device in India and a lambda server in Ireland, and keeping this a closely guarded secret.

The final solution was simple: I deleted my US lambda and created a new one with identical settings in EU-West1.
Now discovery went smooth.

One Additional note: In the Alexa developer console under Smart Home service endpoint, I had to check the box 'Europe, India' and supply the ARN of my Irish lambda.

Comment: I faced the same issue. I was using us-east-1, rather I had to use eu-west-1. Such a major documentation error done by alexa team.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Everything was configured correctly but no **Discover Request** (Alexa.Discovery) was sent to the lambda function.

In the end **it was a problem with the echosim service (echosim.io)** which acts as an simulated alexa device.

The documentation mentions that the devices (echo) must be in the same region as your lambda function otherwise your lambda is not being called.

> For discovery of smart home devices to succeed, you must choose the region where the devices are located.
> https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smarthome/steps-to-build-a-smart-home-skill.html#create-a-lambda-function

**Further explanation:**
Every alexa developer accounts needs a alexa device connected to it otherwise you can not use the alexa simulator. 
The device can be:

- a real alexa device (Amazon echo, Amazon echo dot, ...)
- a smartphone with the alexa app
- a simulated device (echosim.io)

It seems that the echosim is located in the US and the lambda I deployed was in Europe. I removed the echosim and installed the alexa app on my phone and logged in with the developer account. Afterwards the device discovery was working fine.